# Is it possible to redefine fst without using pattern matching?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, tuples

I've been using Haskell for about a year now because I'm writing a paper on it. In one of the first chapters I talk about pattern matching, and refer to the function

```
fst :: (a,b) -> a
```

to demonstrate the usefulness of it. In the text I say that it "would be more convoluted" to implement `fst` without using pattern matching. Out of interest I started thinking about how I'd do this, but can't seem to think of any way that doesn't use pattern matching in one way or another, the best thing I can think of is

```
fst' tuple = let (first, second) = tuple
             in first
```

but that essentially still uses pattern matching! Is there a way to access the inner values of a tuple without pattern matching?

Comment: Only if you define pairs as `type Tuple a b = forall r . (a -> b -> r) -> r`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to extract the arguments of a data constructor is to pattern match on it.  You can do the pattern matching manually, or call a function (like `fst`) which does it for you - but either way, the pattern matching is being done somewhere.

Comment: Oh yeah, I totally forgot to generalise the problem to all data constructors, in which case it's pretty obvious! Thanks a lot.